# How can I send URL to receiver which is clickable in whatsAPI?

Tags: php, api, sockets, whatsapp

I tried to send URL to the receiver through *whatsAPI*, but the receiver got the url as plain text.

How can I send URL to the receiver's end which is really clickable?

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple way to share text messages on whatsapp thru web. (If you don't have any special reason to use API)

Ref : http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

Above method will send links, which are really clickable.